# Postgres: authentication fails when try to login with different unix user

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I have a user `hduser` and user `postgres`,

with **hduser**:

```
hduser@master:/$ psql -Upostgres -W analytics
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
hduser@master:/$
```

with **postgres**:

```
postgres@master:/opt/pentaho/biserver-ce$ psql -Upostgres -W analytics
Password for user postgres: 
psql (8.4.9)
Type "help" for help.

analytics=#
```

How can I login to same database with a different user like `hduser` or some other?

Thank you

Answer (score 20):

The default configuration of PostgreSQL allows "local" access to a database only to database users which have the same name as the OS user. "local" means without any IP traffic using only the Unix-Domain sockets. See the documentation for the configuration file `pg_hba.conf` especially the lines starting with "local" and the authentication method "peer" or "ident".

On the other hand accessing postgres using an IP transport channels is by default configured to use passwords IF there IS a password. Therefore this should help youfor normal users.

```
foouser@host$ psql -U baruser -h 127.0.0.1 database
```

The bad message is, that the DB superuser `postgres` does NOT have a password by default, so you must set one first.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres handles authentication and authorization separately.

Authentication options are configured in the file: pg_hba.conf -- this file describes what authentication methods users are allowed to use, and which hosts they can connect from.

Authorization to access databases and tables is configured by issuing GRANT statements in SQL.

On most Linux systems, the Postgres user is setup to use 'ident' authentication, and does not have a password by default, so if you wish to login using a password, you'll need to configure that with a SQL statement, and then alter your pg_hba.conf to allow the user postgres to login using a password:

`ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD password`

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a [.pgpass](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass) file for hduser

Answer (score -3):

I added the following in `pg_hba.conf` and it got fixed

```
local   all         all                         trust
```

Comment: Please note that this allows access of all local system users to all databases without a password, do you really want this!?

Comment: You should really use `md5' instead, unless you want any local user to be free to access any database without auth.